# Wordpress loading a header file other than the one specified in the theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a head.php file with a very simple markup.

Then in my index.php of the theme file, I have put the following code:

```
<?php
get_header(); 
?>
```

But when I visit the site, it loads a wordpress default header (the one specified in the theme customization from wp amdin).

What should I do to avoid this?

Comment: To get the basic question out of the way, does your theme have a header.php file? And is it in the current directory?

Comment: If you actually do mean `head.php` and not `header.php`, you need to rename this file to `header.php`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing your code in the head.php file, why don't you use header.php file itself? This will save your extra efforts of calling your custom files explicitly